# How to make number of recycle view items in each row dependent on their content size

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I have a large number of items that I want to arrange them like this:
[where the image is](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jEWOq.png)
But I don't want to use Chipgroup and prefer using recyclerview because searching and filtering the items is easier. How can I make a list like that with recyclerview?

Comment: I have found two different libraries that will be be helpful for what are looking for :

https://github.com/rantianhua/AssembleEssay (is not in english but you can see the code)

https://github.com/xiaofeng-han/AndroidLibs/tree/master/flowlayoutmanager (I don't know if this is what are you looking for but it is very similar I think)

Let me know if that helps you :)

Comment: @Sergio Thank you so much ,  FlowLayoutManger is what is was looking for!

Comment: Perfect @drsheid!! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make it [StaggeredGridLayoutManager](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/StaggeredGridLayoutManager)

you can go through this [example](https://www.android4dev.com/how-to-use-recyclerview-with-staggeredgridlayoutmanager-android-kotlin/)

Comment: Thank you Muhamed. StaggeredGridLayoutManger and the FlowLayouManger library both solve my problem.

Comment: @drsehid \\ you are most welcome .. it's my pleasure to help you ^_^

Comment: I did that but because I don't have enough reputations it's not public!

Comment: I'm a new user and my reputations are less than 15!

Comment: @drsehid \\ ok bro .. never mind 
if you need anything else .. we are always here <3